# How can I decrease error highlighting in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

how I can decrease the error highlighting in vscode and get only the "wave" underling under the error instead of also the red highlight of all the line as you can see in the image below?[image]

Answer (score 0):

---

## Customizing Error Highlights

---

> ###### Note from Answer's Original Author
>
> Below is a long answer that explains how to configure the editor to produce any error-highlighting effect you want. If you want a quick answer, scroll to the very last example and read that.

---

Customizing the Error highlighting, and squiggle lines is an easy to accomplish task. It can be done one of two ways.

1. You can create a theme that produces the desired result.
2. You can configure your Global or Workspace `settings.json` file to produce the desired result.

They are intrinsically the same thing, its just a matter of how you want VS Code to load the settings and apply them to the editor, and whether or not you want to make the colorization-configuration you create extensible, so that it can be distributed as an extension in the **[Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/VSCode)**.

Below, I will demonstrate how to add the squiggles through a custom configuration in your settings.json file, as it is the most straight forward method for explaining how to custom color the Error highlighting in the editor. At the the very end of this answer I will include a link to the "Theme Development" documentation, so that you can apply what you learn in this answer to an extensible theme if that's something you desire to do.

---

### [Color Customization Properties](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors)

---

The squiggle-lines & background-highlighting your asking about are what you call **"themeable"**. They are "themeable" entities that have a property that can be configured specifically to customize their appearance. I have included the list of `editor.colorCusomization` properties, that when configured correctly, will produce the result your looking for.

*"There are 3 different setting groups bellow, each highlights a different statuses squiggle lines, and background highlight: Error, Warning & Info."*

I have included images that show how each snippet I included renders the different statuses in the editor, but you should probably still add them to your editor so you get a feel for them, but its up to you. Either way, the settings in the snippets displayed below are intended to be placed in your global, or workspace, `settings.json` file.

```
//  @file  "./.vscode/settings.json"

{
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        /*
        ________________________________
        EDITOR ERROR STATUS HIGHLIGHTING */
        "editorError.foreground": "#FF0000",
        "editorError.background": "#ff0000",
        "editorError.border": "#ff0000",
        /*

        __________________________________
        EDITOR WARNING STATUS HIGHLIGHTING */
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#FFFF00",
        "editorWarning.background": "#FFFF00",
        "editorWarning.border": "#FFFF00",
        /*

        _______________________________
        EDITOR INFO STATUS HIGHLIGHTING */
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#22EE00",
        "editorInfo.background": "#22EE00",
        "editorInfo.border": "#22EE00",
    },
}
```

The configuration above does not produce a desirable result for real-time application, but it does offer a result that's quite useful for teaching.

###### This image communicates what the code in the snippet above produces when applied to a VS Code configuration.

[image]

As I said already, the result is not desirable, but it is a good example of what the properties do, and how much they can affect your environment. In case someone reading doesn't realize what is going on in the image. The Green, Yellow & Red block are an Error, Warning, and Info-queue that I intentionally prompted to display the settings I posted in the first snippet.

---

#### Snippet 2: Lets Change the Settings a Bit

---

At this point there isn't much to say. I will post a couple snippets, and you need to interpret the results.

###### Here are the same settings, but with different values assigned to them:

```
//  @file  "./.vscode/settings.json"
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        /*

        ________________________________
        EDITOR ERROR STATUS HIGHLIGHTING            */
        "editorError.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorError.background": "#ff003333",
        "editorError.border": "#00000000",
        /*

        __________________________________
        EDITOR WARNING STATUS HIGHLIGHTING          */
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.background": "#ffff0022",
        "editorWarning.border": "#00000000",
        /*

        __________________________________
        EDITOR INFO STATUS HIGHLIGHTING          */
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.background": "#22EE0022",
        "editorInfo.border": "#00000000",
    },
}
```

In the image below, you can see that the #2 snippet above set the backgrounds to be transparent. It also removed the border, which if you noticed, is actually covering the squiggle line in the first image.

[image]

---

#### Last Example: The Squiggle Only Config

---

```
//  @file  "./.vscode/settings.json"

{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        /*

        ________________________________
        EDITOR ERROR STATUS HIGHLIGHTING            */
        "editorError.foreground": "#FF2233",
        "editorError.background": "#00000000",
        "editorError.border": "#00000000",
        /*

        __________________________________
        EDITOR WARNING STATUS HIGHLIGHTING          */
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#FFFF00",
        "editorWarning.background": "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.border": "#00000000",
        /*

        __________________________________
        EDITOR INFO STATUS HIGHLIGHTING          */
        "editorInfo.foreground": "#33FF11",
        "editorInfo.background": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.border": "#00000000",
    },
}
```

Here is the exact example you were looking for. This can be added to vscode, as I stated above, in several different ways. The quickest and direct is by simply adding the snippet above to your projects `./.vscode/settings.json` file. You can also set it in a theme, or in your global `settings.json` file.

###### Image of "Squiggles Only Config"

[image]

As I said above, one way of achieving the configuration is by adding the last snippet to a theme. How to do that is beyond the scope of this Q&A, but it is well documented **[HERE (VSCode's Official Docs Page).](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/color-theme)**.

Comment: This answer came at the cost of a file I had just started writing lol. I needed something to introduce errors and warnings into.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanations, but in my global setting.json I haven't any customization, some month ago I remember that I enabled it before that time I have only the wave underlining, are you sure I have to write a custom theme?

Comment: I have tried your example but that red highlight I show in the question image doens't go away, so as I mention in my previous comment, there is something that I have enabled to have that somewhere

Comment: I solved the problem uninstalling completely vscode and installing it again

Comment: no you dont have to write a cuswtom theme, you just have to add it to your settings.json file. A custom theme is one way of doing it. Reinstalling VSCode probably just reset what ever theme you had equipped that was changing the highlighting.

Comment: If you look at the last example I showed, you could have just added  that to your ".vscode/settings.json" as I said.